# proper way to call a program method on Solana from client, connected to wallet

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, solana, phantom-wallet

I need to call something like this:

```
const tx = await program.methods.list(price, expiryTime).accounts(dataToSend).signers([wallet]).rpc()
```

and I don't know what to put in the signers array, cause it needs a signer and signer needs secret key, but I can not access the secret key when I'm connected to the wallet (using solana-wallet-adapter).

is there another way to call it? or is there some other method to use?

Comment: where did you get that code from? which package is that

Comment: @Yilmaz program is an Anchor program